# Which is better: "tasked with doing" or "tasked to do"?

Tags: grammar, construction

As the heading says: Which is the better alternative – *tasked with doing* or *tasked to do*? Or are they equally good, but used in different contexts? In that case, what's the difference between them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*tasked with* is certainly more common.

When used passively

[image]

When used actively

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either will do. My personal taste is for fewer words when possible, so would choose "tasked to do" .

In context, I would try for neither.
Name the task directly rather than as a request to do it. So

- ... tasked to clean the kitchen.

rather than

- ... tasked to do the kitchen cleanup.

**Edit** after reading the answer from @AndrewTobilko :

- ... tasked with the kitchen cleanup.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the naming of the task straight away – I just used "do" as a dummy for whatever verb would be relevant in the context :) Thanks!